# My bootstrap dropdown menu works on local host but not on github

Tags: jekyll, dropdown, navbar, github-pages

I made a blog recently and it goes something like this, with most of it just copied from bootstrap.However, the dropdown menu works on local host but not on github pages.

```html
<!--add bootstrap-->
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
          <script src="{{ '/assets/js/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js' | relative_url }}" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
          <script src="{{ '/assets/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js' | relative_url }}" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

          
          <!--dropdown-->          
          <div class='nav-item dropdown'>
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle header__link" href="#" role='menu' id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            More
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" id='dropdown'>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="page4.html">Interests</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a>
                         </div>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be because some of the external `.js` files are returning `Error 404`.
**Now**, try adding a `.`[dot] before the first slash, i.e. , use `./assets/js/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js` and `./assets/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js` .

**And if the above solution solves the problem, then what caused the Problem was its URL. Please read the following points mentioned below, they might help you understand the problem**:

1. If the name of your GitHub repository is, let's say, `example`, so the your GitHub pages will be published at your `https://your-username.github.io/example/`
2. and if your repository has `.github.io` in its name, like `example.github.io` then your GitHub Pages will be published at `https://your-username.github.io/example.github.io/` and also at `https://example.github.io`.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when there are issues with drop downs in bootstrap it is because of missing Popper.js. Check out the imports they are using here including **Popper.js**

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/#starter-template